# Django select_related - should I use?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a model like:

```
class A(models.Model):
    number = models.SmallIntegerField()

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.OneToOneField(A)
```

and I want to do something like that:

```
b = B.objects.get(pk=1)
b.a.number = 5
b.a.save()
```

My question is: Should I use `.select_related('a')` in this case?

```
b = B.objects.select_related('a').get(pk=1)
```

Comment: You can if you want to - its a performance enhancer.

Comment: depends on how many records you are doing, and where you are doing the assignment. Check your database and see how many SQL calls are made to do it that way, vs .select_related.

Comment: For the example you give, you can fetch the `a` directly, by filtering on the reverse relation: `a = A.objects.get(b__pk=1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to summarize: Yes. Without `select_related` you will have to do two separate database queries (one for getting the `b`, and one for getting the associated `a`). With `select_related` you can get everything in one query.